# Why hand cursor is used for navigational elements?

Tags: discussion, design

According to this, https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/36874/52877

Hand cursor is used only for navigational purpose.

In case of

[image: cursor hand]

While hovering on action element (i.e. help), we can see hand cursor

People may hesitate to click on that.